# Multiple CSS animations: pausing does not show current frame on Safari

Tags: safari, css-animations, pause

Has anyone ever stumbled upon something similar on Safari ?

I defined three animation names for the same CSS selector, making sure the delay for each animation is higher than the duration of the previous animations

```
.bg_anim {
    animation-delay: 0s, 5s, 10s;
    animation-duration: 3s, 3s, 3s;
    animation-name: blueToRed, redToYellow, yellowToBlack;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards, forwards;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 5s, 10s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s, 3s, 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: blueToRed, redToYellow, yellowToBlack;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes blueToRed {
    0%   {background-color: blue}
    100% {background-color: red}
}

@-webkit-keyframes blueToRed {
    0%   {background-color: blue}
    100% {background-color: red}
}

@keyframes redToYellow {
    0%   {background-color: red}
    100% {background-color: yellow}
}

@-webkit-keyframes redToYellow {
    0%   {background-color: red}
    100% {background-color: yellow}
}

@keyframes yellowToBlack {
    0%   {background-color: yellow}
    100% {background-color: black}
}

@-webkit-keyframes yellowToBlack {
    0%   {background-color: yellow}
    100% {background-color: black}
}
```

When the series of animations start, a pause always displays the last frame of the last animation, rather than the current frame of the current animation

For a full version of the example, see https://jsfiddle.net/mrgiba/qtco0dcr/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we are working at a professional company, and we noticed the same problem. We tested this throughly and found that there is no work around and this is a serious bug. You can only pause a single animation in safari. Safari is unable to pause anything correctly with any kind of multiple animations (for example stacked elements with each single animation can't be paused either, exaclty same problem, no matter what you do).

Our solution was to remove safari from the list of browsers we code for. This is no joke.